# i(1054, "Unknown column 'rango_category.slug' in 'field list'") Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to create a slug field in a Django project.
However I keep getting this error when trying to access the categories on django admin, I'm new to Django and just trying to keep up with a tutorial.

```
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| rango_category | CREATE TABLE `rango_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Categories"


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you don't have a `slug` field in you `rango_category` table.

In the corresponding model for the `rango_category` table, let's say `RangoCategory` model add a slug field:

```
class RangoCategory(models.Model):
    id = ...
    likes = ...
    name = ...
    views = ...
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, it will probably ask for a value to set to the existing rows.

This will create a slug field in you db table.

Comment: Hi there @Gocht, I already have that in my model which is the curious part. What can I do then?

Comment: I'm trying to run a populate_script, when I migrated Django gave me 3 options. 1. To add a default value for slug, 2. To leave it like that  or 3. To change it manually, I chose number 2 maybe here's the error and I should provided slug an empty value with ' ' and then migrate

Comment: @Juanvulcano It's a unique field, so if you provide `''` for all the existing rows it's wrong. Migrations is not being applied since you have not provided a value for existing rows. I would mark it as `null=True, blank=True` in models, run migrations and after migrations is done, run the save method in every object via django console (python manage.py shell) to get a slug value, and then remove `null=True blank=True` from model definition.